# How to take the yesterday date in "dd/mm/YYYY" format in a SoQL query?

Tags: bash, soql

The data set I am taking information from has a column date in the format dd/mm/YYYY. Which command could I use in order to take these  values?

query="SELECT city,AVG(figure) WHERE class = 'xxxx' AND city = 'MyCity' date = 'yesterday_date' GROUP BY City ORDER BY City"

Thank you in advance,
Toni Reina

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question, you can do something like this with bash :

```
yesterday=$(date --date=' 1 days ago' '+%d/%m/%Y')
```

then you can pass the variable as below :

```
query="SELECT name WHERE data=${yesterday}"
```

Comment: Very appreciated your reply Mahmoud. Let me check if it works, thank you.